# domain of convergence: Laplace transform of $\sin{bt}$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

To find Laplace transform of $\sin{bt}$, I get
[image]

How to find the domain of convergence.

Attempt:

It seems to me that it will be for all $s-ib>0$ (the domain for $\mathscr{L}(e^{bt})$ is $\forall ~s-a>0$) but the actual answer I know $s>0$.

Also $\mathscr{L}(e^{at}\sin{bt})=\frac{b}{(s-a)^2+b^2}$ then what will be domain of convergencce of $\mathscr{L}(e^{at}\sin{bt})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the Laplace Transform of $\sin(bt)$ is given by

$$\mathscr{L}\{\sin(bt)\}(s)=\int_0^\infty \sin(bt)e^{-st}\,dt \tag 1$$

We have the estimate

$$\left|\int_0^L \sin(bt)e^{-st}\,dt\right|\le \int_0^L e^{-\text{Re}(s)t}\,dt=\frac{1-e^{-\text{Re}(s)L}}{\text{Re}(s)}$$

Evidently, the integral in $(1)$ converges whenever $\text{Re}(s)>0$.

If $\text{Re}(s)\le  0$, then it is easy to see that the integral diverges.

Therefore, the domain of convergence is $\text{Re}(s)>0$ as was to be shown!

Comment: then what will be the domain of convergence of $\mathscr{L}(e^{at}\sin{bt})=\frac{b}{(s-a)^2+b^2}$?

Comment: $$\text{Re}(s-a)>0$$